# cannot load such file error when running local gem

Tags: ruby

I am trying to test out a simple local gem that I am working on but I am getting an error when testing the gem locally. I set the path to the local gem in my project's Gemfile.

**Gemfile**

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

git_source(:github) {|repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }

gem "rake"

gem "valet-tasks", path: "../../Gems/valet-tasks"
```

**Rakefile**

```rb
require 'valet-tasks'
```

**The is the error I get:**

```rb
rake -T --trace
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- valet-tasks
/Users/myuser/Sites/mysite/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Here is how my valet-tasks Gem looks like:

**Gemfile**

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

# Specify your gem's dependencies in valet-tasks.gemspec
gemspec

gem "rake", "~> 13.0"
```

**lib/valet-tasks.rb**

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rake'
require 'rake/tasklib'

require_relative "valet-tasks/version"
require_relative 'valet-tasks/hello'

module ValetTasks
  class Error < StandardError; end
  # Your code goes here...
end
```

**lib/valet-tasks/hello.rb**

```rb
module ValetTasks
  module Task
    include Rake::DSL if defined? Rake::DSL

      class Hello < ::Rake::TaskLib
      def initialize
        super

        namespace :hello do
          desc 'Prints hello'
          task :one do
            puts 'Testing one two three'
          end
        end

      end
    end
  end
end

ValetTasks::Task::Hello.new
```

I feel like everything is set up correctly. Could it be that this is not possible inside a Rakefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `bundle exec`

```
bundle exec rake -T
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Once I install the Gem without use the remote path, will I be able to call the command without `bundle exec`?

Comment: No, you will still need `bundle exec`. Alternatively, you could add `require 'bundler/setup'` to your `Rakefile`.